# break out of try catch and if else statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

I have the code block as below. I need to stop after i throw the exceptions in the elseif or else statements and not return the final return statement after the try catch if it goes into the elseif or else statements.

Comment: Instead of catching and throwing `Exception` (which would end up being overly-generic), instead use _specific_ exceptions for _specific_ errors. Making a new exception class is as simple as extending `Exception` or `RuntimeException`, and providing a constructor with super.

Comment: "not return the final return statement after the try catch" why is your return statement after the catch block, then?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Both the else clauses throw exceptions, which will both then be caught by the catch block, and a new Exception thrown. There are other logical errors in the code, but it appears that the return statement will never be executed if either of the else clauses are.

Comment: because it throws an error "missing return statement" if i put it the return inside the if statement @njzk2

Comment: @crig i removed the throw in catch block. now how do i achieve the solution for the question? and P.S i dont want the return to be executed if it goes into either of the else statements thats why i wrote it like that

Comment: I'm still unclear on the problem. You don't want to return a JWT token on a failed logon, that is clear - there's no token to return.  You have a couple of choices - when you detect a logon failure throw an exception - which your code previously did, or return null.  Either case is easy to achieve - in the IF/THEN clauses that detect the errors, throw the exception or return null. You have good log comments in your code, should be easy to trace what is happening if you are not entering the proper blocks of code that detect the errors.

Comment: Perhaps what is messing you up is that your catch statement appears to be intended to only catch the actual failed logon error, but it wraps all the other logic for session count errors as well. So when those blocks detect and throw exceptions they are being caught by your code that is intended to handle only logon errors. You can move that try/catch around just the two lines that attempt a logon and perhaps things will behave more as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Try object that wraps around the exception as described in https://dzone.com/articles/why-try-better-exception-handling-in-java-with-try.

Answer (score 0):

Move the return statement inside the if condition then

Comment: if i do that, it shows an error"missing return statement"